# one to many relation and get information in balde laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i have 2 table that they have one to many relation and i want to get all client information and name user in blade

it is user model

```
 public function FirstClients(){

        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\FirstClient");
    }
```

it is client  model

```
 public function User(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
```

it is controller

```
   $allclients= DB::table('first_clients')->get();

        return view('admin.client.allclients' , compact('allclients'));
```

and this is blade

```
@foreach ($allclients as $client)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $client->user->name}}</td>
                        <tr/>
@endforeach
```

and i have this error

Undefined property: stdClass::$user

Comment: can you elaborate on the question, which model or table you want to access is it, client or user. if you want to access through the client model then use eloquent queries with relation e.g: if I want to access the user model with relation of address  then it should be like  USERMODEL::with('relation_name')->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method name you are using is case sensitive. Try to use camelCase for relations in Models 
Now you have to change your method name to `user()`

Client Model

```
public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

Blade View

```
@foreach ($allclients as $client)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $client->user->name}}</td>
  <tr/>
@endforeach
```

Controller  
You need to use eloquent to use relations.

```
$allclients= FirstClient::with('user')->get();

return view('admin.client.allclients' , compact('allclients'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use *first_clients* class to fetch data representation in model object Client
e.g.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class FirstClient extends Model
    {
        /**
         * The table associated with the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'first_clients';
    
    
        public function user(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
        }
    
    
    }
```

In your controller

```
$allclients = FisrstClient::all();

return view('admin.client.allclients', compact('allclients'));
```

Comment: In your first_clients table you must have user_id column, is this exists ?